# known issues ie 9 notes 853

Tags: xpages

are there known issues when developing xpage in 853 when using ie9.

currently i.have an xpage with a radiobutton which does have a onchange partial refresh. It does not work on ie9. on firefox it does work.

Comment: The onchange event has never worked correctly in IE.

Comment: Is there fix for IE to let it work correctly. Or should I just add a custom event handler which kicks of the server handler.

Comment: Bug in IE9 - here's a workaround

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510907/help-ie9-onchange-event-doesnt-fire-when-value-is-modified-by-an-onkeydown-s

Comment: Also check this: http://www.fss.de/fss/domblog.nsf/dx/xpages-und-der-ie9-kompatibilit%C3%A4tsmodus.htm (you might need Google translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem yesterday, the `onclick()` with an `onchange()` worked for me - not ideal though

```
<xp:eventHandler
event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
refreshId="PanTransfer" id="eventHandler2"></xp:eventHandler>
<xp:eventHandler
event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="PanTransfer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick() event on checkboxes or radio buttons, that works in both browsers.

Comment: This seems to work but has the side effect that you have to move away from the control (with the mouse) before the onclick is being submitted.. Or people have to double-click..